# How to use try-catch block in PHP CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working in PHP CodeIgniter and when I am trying to apply a try and catch block in my code then it is not working and does not handle the error. I have tried the try-catch block in both place Model and Controller but it is not working. My code is shown below.

```
try {
            $data = array(
                'userid' => '101',
                'pass' => '123456',
                'usertyp' => 2,
                'createddate' => "now()");
             $this->db->insert('login', $data);
     }
     catch (Exception $ex) 
     {
            echo $ex;
     }
```

Whatever the error occurred when I try to insert the record in database then it must be handled by the catch block but here it's not going happen.

Comment: Are you getting any error over here and instead of `echo $ex;` try using `flashmessage`

Comment: yes I got error, when I am trying to insert record.

Comment: And whats the error you were getting over here

Comment: can you post stack trace of the error ? you will have to catch the specific exception which i think in your case would be `PDOException`

Comment: Use $ex->getMessage(); to get the actual error message for the exception.

Comment: actually the above code does not give any error but to generate error I changed the "now()" function to "now("  so in this case it will generate error but this error should be handled by try and catch block but here try and catch is not working. Actually I want to handled any type of error in try and catch block.

Comment: and you still want to know that what error occurred here so i.e.                             A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

ERROR: column "usertyp" of relation "login" does not exist LINE 1: INSERT INTO "login" ("userid", "pass", "usertyp", "createdda... ^

INSERT INTO "login" ("userid", "pass", "usertyp", "createddate") VALUES ('P0201023', 'P0201023', 2, 'now)')

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/c/application/models/State/CollegeRegister.php

Line Number: 72